# get particular value from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

using javascript how can i get `0e783d248f0e27408d3a6c043f44f337c54235ce` from below string

my     `console.log(stdout);` prints

```
 status.html:commit 0e783d248f0e27408d3a6c043f44f337c54235ce
```

The value `0e783d248f0e27408d3a6c043f44f337c54235ce` will be changing.

Am trying to find that key

Comment: `string.split('commit').pop();`

Comment: please post as answer so that i can accept your anser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `commit` is a constant, and you just need the rest of the string from `commit` to the end, you can split the string on `commit` and pop of the last part

```
string.split('commit').pop();
```

It will leave an extra space, but you can either trim that off, or just add a space in

```
split('commit ')
//           ^ space
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` function:

```
stdout.split("status.html:commit ")[1]
```

Or `match`:

```
stdout.match("status.html:commit (.*)").pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .[pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) function.

```
var str = "status.html:commit 0e783d248f0e27408d3a6c043f44f337c54235ce";
str.split("commit").pop().trim()
```